# Why is the white up-pointing triangle smaller (html entities)?

Tags: html, html-entities

How to fix this? Is there a different code for this triangle, in the correct scale?

```css
p{
  font-size:30px
}
```

```html
<h2>Why is &#9651; smaller than the others?</h2>
<p>Code 9650 &#9650;</p>
<p>Code 9651 &#9651;</p>
<p>Code 9660 &#9660;</p>
<p>Code 9661 &#9661;</p>
```

In Chrome v59:

[image]

Comment: When I run the code snippet it is not smaller

Comment: It is in Chrome but not in Firefox, haven't checked ie - perhaps it's a Chrome bug?

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox looks good

http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/17/0706/h_1499338711_8470189_832d1075d2.jpeg

Comment: In Chrome(59.0.3071.115) https://pasteboard.co/GzFwQ8J.png

Comment: Maybe it's the default font on your system? Try adding this to the `p` CSS rule: `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`.

Comment: @Catalyst, still the same problem...

Comment: you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/PlVegTE.png) in [graphemica](http://graphemica.com/) that they have a small height difference

Comment: @BharathShetty What OS are you on?

Comment: @Darren Sweeney Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Then I'd says it's a Windows Chrome issue - @TheodoreK. What OS are you on?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: FYI, I've raised a bug on this with chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=739693

Comment: No answers yet? Strange...